# How do i create a subdomain using ssh commands?

Tags: ssh, subdomain

I tried to search over the interner but i found nothing. I have a ssh access to a server. I want to create a **subdomain**. How can I do that?  If you can suggest any tutorials, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Copy a sample db file to /var/named/ directory

cp -p /var/named/existingdomain.com.db /var/named/newdomain.com.db

Open /etc/named.conf file and copy/paste an entry at the bottom for the new domain.

Open httpd.conf and copy/paste a virtualhost and edit it to reflect subdomain and corresponding document root.

Restart named and apache.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30536587)